# Meteor.call() format js object into correct rest query

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, rest, meteor

I am trying to do an API call to a wordpress rest api. A working call from the console looks like this:

```
http://dev.thomastraum.com/wp-json/posts?type=tt_works&filter[work_categories]= all&filter[posts_per_page]=1
```

A "handwritten" working call from Meteor looks like this:

```
    return Meteor.http.call("GET", Settings.wpdomain + "/wp-json/posts", {params: {'type':'tt_works','filter[work_categories]':'all','filter[posts_per_page]':'1'}});
```

Now my question is, how can I pass javascript objects to the meteor call and they end up being in the right format. To me the above calls look like they should be represented like this:

```
ArchiveQuery = {
type:'tt_works',
filter:{
    work_categories:'all',
    posts_per_page:1
}
};
```

but if I pass it

```
return Meteor.http.call("GET", Settings.wpdomain + "/wp-json/posts", {params:ArchiveQuery);
```

it returns me all posts with the type parameter of `tt_works` and ignores all the rest of the query. I tried `EJSON.stringify(ArchiveQuery)` but it formats the query differently, with `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query format you need doesn't look like a very common one. I think the easiest solution will be to format your object yourself:

```
var fillQuery = function(query, prefix, object) {
  _.each(object, function(val, key) {
    var k = (prefix) ? prefix + '[' + key + ']' : key;
    if(_.isObject(val)) {
      fillQuery(query, k, val);
    } else {
      query[k] = '' + val;
    }
  });
  return query;
};

var objectToQuery = function(object) {
  return fillQuery({}, null, object);
};
```

See [here](http://repl.it/Yjv/3) in action.

Comment: thanks! I was thinking of writing a function to do just that, but yours looks so much better than what I would have come up with.